# jQuery autocomplete rendering results that are hidden

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use the autocomplete widget in jQuery however when I start typing nothing shows up below it. I can tell it's doing something becasue as I type I can see the scroll bar on the page changing as the list gets shorter, but I can't see the results. My code is below. Any help is appreciated with this.

My controller method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult GetUsers(string query)
    {
        var empName = from u in HomeModel.CombineNames()
                      where u.StartsWith(query)
                      select u.Distinct().ToArray();
        return Json(empName);
    }
```

My View looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetUsers',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",


                data: { query: request.term },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return { label: item, value: item };
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
</script>
<input  type="text" id = "autocomplete"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a few things, like render item, cache managment.

the code should looks something like this: (assuming your action return an array of string)

```
var cache = {},lastXhr;
            $( "input#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
                minLength: 4,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var term = request.term;
                    if (term in cache) {
                        response(cache[term]);
                        return;
                    }
                    var descripcion = new Array();
                    peticion = $.getJSON('/Home/GetUsers',{ query: request.term }, function (data, status, xhr) {
                        for (d in data) {
                            descripcion.push(data[d]);
                        }
                        cache[term] = descripcion;
                        if (xhr === peticion) {
                            response(descripcion);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $("input#autocomplete" ).val( ui.item);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + item +  " </a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I try to implement this it says that _renderItem is null or undefined.

Comment: which version of jquery and jquery ui are you using?

Comment: jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.20

Comment: I had the same error with jQuery 1.4 and was solved when updated to 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Try using the inspection tools of your browser to examine the area where your scroll bar is changing.  If the elements are present, you likely need to make some changes to the CSS so your text color is different from the background color (or some other display-related issue).

Comment: I removed the CSS from the page to check and I still have the same issue.